# Sort and calculation in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

For each record, there is a particular calculated field. The value of that field is obtained by the difference of the value in the next record. So sorting should be correct for the right value of this field. But now the report shown to the user is grouped in many sections and sorted in different ways, but I want the field to be of right value (based on one sort).

In short, how can I sort the records based on,say 'A', and do the calculation and display it based on different combinations of sort?

Links, pointers appreciated.

Example:
Original sort by Age for calculation

```
Name Age Diff
-------------
Mark  60   5
Pete  65   7
Nath  72   0
```

Values of Diff should still hold in different sort

```
Name Age Diff
-------------
Mark  60   5
Nath  72   0
Pete  65   7
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you are calculating the age difference?

Comment: So for Mark, it will be the difference between his age and his next older guy's age. So 65 (Pete's) - 60 = 5 will be Mark's Diff. For Nath, there is no one older than him so 0.

Comment: Close, I was actually asking about the actual formula. Is this being done in CR or at the data source?

Comment: Sorry. This is a CR Formula - I'm making this up, but similar. (The actual has date.)     Next({Emp.age}) - {Emp.age}

Comment: Simple enough.  Except I don't think CR can both sort your data one way for your calculation and then sort it another way for display.  It's just a reporting program.  I recommend moving your calculation back to the data source (perhaps a SQL query that dumps your data into a staging table, ranks it, and joins onto itself for the calculation).  That way, since CR sees the data already calculated, all it has to do is sort by Name.

Comment: Well, it was that way, and we were using ttx capability. Since this wont be supported in the future, all was moved to crystal...and now we have this problem. Thanks for your comments.